# I want to add a scrollbar to the screen of my app but I'm using grid instead of pack and I don't want to use a canvas. I'm a beginner by the way

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Iv'e tried a bunch of random things. I know I'm supposed to be specific when explaining this but I don't really know what to say. I made a scrollbar in a def function, it was in a whole new screen and I added it to a text box. So I'm wondering if I can just add my main scrollbar to the frame/screen in my main window. My previous scrollbar is in the recipe_steps function.

Comment: Are you just wanting to scroll a text widget, or do you want to scroll a collection of widgets?

Comment: It's okay now, I found a person on here that was having the same problem as me and they found someone who solved the problem! But thanks for the consideration, have a nice day. :)

Comment: Please delete the question if you no longer need an answer.